# form not refreshing in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a form that shows names from the a table in access database, then on a button click, I move to form2 where I make some changes, like rename one field, on ok click, the change is made in the database, and I comes back to `form1`, but  the change is not reflected back.

To see the change , I have to restart the program.

I tried the form.refresh and form.invalidate but nothing works.

I read somewhere that threading has to be done, but I am new to c# and have no idea of threading.

Can someone suggest any way other than threading to do this.
And if threading is the only way, please suggest some good resource and example.

Comment: did you try `gridView1.Refresh();` ?

Answer (score 0):

The data on `form1` doesn't change just because you have updated the underlying data.

You need to refetch the data from the database and repopulate `form1` when returning from your `form2`.

You can do this by registering with the `form2.Closing` event and in the event handler do the refetch and repopulation.

Answer (score 0):

Create an accessor to your control that you wish to update or pass a refernece of `Form1` to `Form2`. If you go down the accessor root you could try in `Form1` having

```
public dataGridView
{
    get { return this.dataGridView1; }
    set { this.dataGridView1 = value; }
}
```

You could then update from `Form2` using

```
Form1 accessForm1 = (Form1)this.Parent;
accessForm1.dataGridView.Update();
```

Note: to update `DataGridView` in `Form1` using this as well

```
accessForm1.dataGridView.Source = someDataBindingSource;
```

I hope this helps.